# how to use the for loop to extract data from a list of url using php

Tags: php, html

The for loop in the code below does not work properly.

```
 $html= @file_get_html($url);
 $job_array = array();
 foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
  // $links=$html->find('a');
  if (strpos($link->href, '/job-category/') !== false) {
   $job_array[] = $link->href . "<br/>";
  }

  for ($a = 0; $a <= ($link->href); $a++) {
   //$page_number = 20;
   // for ($i = 1; $i <= $page_number; $i++) {
   $html2 = file_get_html($link->href);
   $response = array();
   foreach ($html2->find('div#mainContent') as $header) {
    $response[] = $header->innertext . "<br/>";
    print_r($response);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Do u get any errors?

Comment: Perhaps you ought to explain in a little more detail what you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of the code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$link->href
```

isn't a number and the for loop can't use a non-number to compare $a to and iterate over. Perhaps you can do:

```
    $html= @file_get_html($url); 
    $job_array = array();
    $myNumberToIterateWith = 0;
      foreach($html->find('a') as $link) { 
      // $links=$html->find('a');
        $myNumberToIterateWith++; 
        if (strpos($link->href, '/job-category/') !== false) { 
           $job_array[] = $link->href . " ";
        }

      for ($a = 0; $a <= $myNumberToIterateWith; $a++) {
       //$page_number = 20;
       // for ($i = 1; $i <= $page_number; $i++) {
       $html2 = file_get_html($link->href);
       $response = array();
       foreach ($html2->find('div#mainContent') as $header) {
        $response[] = $header->innertext . "<br/>";
        print_r($response);
       }
      }
```

Though I'm not sure what you wish the result to be. It is helpful to provide clues as to what you wish to accomplish with the code.

Comment: @dolyanne did it help at all?